# How to automate ios app elements using robot framework?

Tags: ios, uitextview, robotframework, device, appium-ios

We are trying to automate ios app (on a device) using robot framework + appium. Below is the xml layout of the page, we want to enter text in the input text.

```
<AppiumAUT>
<UIAApplication name="mobil88" label="mobil88" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
    <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
        <UIAScrollView name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/1" x="0" y="20" width="320" height="548">
            <UIAWebView name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/1/0" x="0" y="20" width="320" height="548">
                <UIATextField name="Email" label="" value="Email" dom="[object Object]" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/1/0/0" x="43" y="219" width="234" height="21">
                </UIATextField>
            </UIAWebView>
        </UIAScrollView>
    </UIAWindow>
    <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/1" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
    </UIAWindow>
    <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/2" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
        <UIAStatusBar name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/2/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="20">
            <UIAElement name="No Service" label="No Service" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/2/0/0" x="6" y="0" width="62" height="20">
            </UIAElement>
            <UIAElement name="3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars" label="3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars" value="SSID" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/2/0/1" x="73" y="0" width="13" height="20">
            </UIAElement>
            <UIAElement name="2:33 PM" label="2:33 PM" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/2/0/2" x="137" y="0" width="50" height="20">
            </UIAElement>
            <UIAElement name="87% battery power, Charging" label="87% battery power, Charging" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top" path="/0/2/0/3" x="255" y="0" width="60" height="20">
            </UIAElement>
        </UIAStatusBar>
    </UIAWindow>
</UIAApplication>
```

We tried below but it's not doing anything or saying that element cannot be found, any advice is welcome. Thank you.

```
//UIATextField[@name="Email"] ,, or
//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]
xpath=//*[@value="Email"]
```

Comment: have you tried //UIATextField[@name="Email" && @value="Email"]?

Comment: @pankajmishra , I just tried and it's giving "WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unexpected character &"

Comment: @tehmiril you have to switch to webview then use the xpath=//*[@value="Email"] then it will work. However it looks like you are using old version of Appium